# Printing in windows console on x,y position

Tags: c, windows, gcc, console, conio

I want to print, in a certain (X,Y) position, on a standard console in windows.
  I tried to use conio.h, but is deprecated/non-existing. There was the gotoxy(x,y) method that seems to be what I want. I've tried these ways, but it just prints extra characters:

```
    printf("%c[%d;%df",0x1B,y,x);
    printf("\x1B%c[%d;%df",0x1B,y,x);
    printf("\x1B[%d;%dH", 0x1B, y, x);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows API call to position the cursor in a console is [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

As someone commented, "curses" is a cross platform console library for doing stuff like this: implementations exist for Windows. ("PDcurses" I think is one such implementation.) These will let you do things like, color, cursor position, etc., and have your program port to other OS, such as Linux.

The `printf` statements you list are escape sequences for several types of terminals out there. Unfortunately, Windows does not use escape sequences for terminal positioning stuff.